# Compare a row substring in one dataframe column with row substring of another dataframe column, and remove non-matching ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with different row counts.

df1 has the problems and count

```
problems          | count
broken, torn      | 10
torn, faded       | 15
worn-out, broken  | 25
faded             | 5
```

df2 has the order_id and problems

```
order_id    | problems
123         | broken
594         | torn
811         | worn-out, broken
```

I need to remove all rows from df1 that do not match the individual problems in the list in df2. And I want to maintain the count of df1.

The final df1 data frame would look like this:

```
problems          | count
broken            | 10
torn              | 15
worn-out, broken  | 25
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try this if your problems are strings:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'problems':['broken, torn', 'torn, faded', 'worn-out, broken', 'faded'],
                   'count':[10,15,25,5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'order_id':[123,594,811],
                   'problems':['broken', 'torn', 'worn-out, broken']})

prob_df2  = df2['problems'].str.split(',\s?').explode()

df1_prob = df1.assign(prob_exp=(df1['problems'].str.split(',\s?')))
df1_exp = df1_prob.explode('prob_exp')

df1_out = (df1_exp[df1_exp['prob_exp'].isin(prob_df2)]
             .groupby(level=0)
             .agg({'count':'first', 'prob_exp': ', '.join}))

df1_out
```

Output:

```
   count          prob_exp
0     10      broken, torn
1     15              torn
2     25  worn-out, broken
```

Details:

1. Create a list of problems from df2 using explode and .str.split with
   a regex that captures the space after comma if present
2. Create a new column in df1 with exploded problems
3. Check to see if problems in df1 are in the df2 problem list
4. Use groupby to combine problems together for each index